# Leaflet different hover and click events

Tags: jquery, mouseevent, bind, mouseover, leaflet

I'm trying to give a popup for the **mouse hover** event *instead of click* on markers and *do some some **other** stuff* (e.g. a func) **when it's get clicked**.

My half successful code which I don't believe will help you think in that direction:

(I'm simply adding a hover on click event)

```
marker[i].on('mouseover', marker[i].bindPopup('hi').openPopup.bind(marker[i]));
```

[i] simply stands for a loop

---

Leaflet's API: http://leaflet.cloudmade.com/reference.html#map-openpopup

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The following code shows a popup when the marker is moused over and does something else when the marker is clicked:

```
marker[i].on('mouseover', function(evt) {
  //evt.target is the marker that is being moused over 
  //bindPopup() does not need to be called here if it was already called
  //somewhere else for this marker.
  evt.target.bindPopup('hi').openPopup();
});
marker[i].on('click', function(evt) {
  //again, evt.target will contain the marker that was clicked
  console.log('you clicked a marker');
});
```

Comment: I've been using leaflet version 0.7 for a long time and the code:

`marker[i].bindPopup('hi').openPopup.bind(marker[i])`

Was working nice. But now with version 1b, if I use that, it triggers an error to the browser console:

_Cannot read property 'lat' of null._

But now I'm using your solution:

`e.target.openPopup()`

does the job just fine (yes, I'm declaring the bindPopup somewhere else).

Answer (score 1):

You are not providing a callback for the mouseover event.

```
marker[i].on('mouseover', function () {
    marker[i].bindPopup('hi').openPopup.bind(marker[i])
});
```

Pass in an anonymous function as your callback, when it is invoked it will do what you want.

I am not very familiar with leaflet api (just started using it a few months back) so there may also be an issue with `marker[i].bindPopup('hi').openPopup.bind(marker[i])` as well.

Comment: Thanks @mark but that's not correct. You see when I have a `marker[i].bindPopup('hi22').openPopup.bind(marker[i])` the mouse over will be binded with a hi22 text. Also the same for `marker[i].on('click', alert('hi22'));`. Finally my callback doesn't need a function to work.